If I update the dependencies to the latest, I cannot see the traces
I am having a FastAPI (0.95.9) application. Using gunicorn with uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker workers.
I am trying to auto-instrument it and pass data to a self-hosted Signoz platform.
When the dependencies are set like this:
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp = "1.20.0"
opentelemetry-distro = "0.41b0"

and I run
poetry lock; poetry install; opentelemetry-bootstrap -a install
auto-instrumentation is working and traces are produced.
If I update the dependencies to the latest
opentelemetry-exporter-otlp = "1.25.0"
opentelemetry-distro = "0.46b0"
# See https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python-contrib/issues/2053
# https://github.com/pypi/support/issues/3353
opentelemetry-instrumentation-aiohttp-server = {git= "https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python-contrib.git", tag="v0.46b0", subdirectory="instrumentation/opentelemetry-instrumentation-aiohttp-server"}

I cannot see any traces. Notice the extra dependency on opentelemetry-instrumentation-aiohttp-server due to a known issue with the library.
Any ideas what might have changed between versions and autoinstrumentation is not working?
